# SLI and dual monitor

Tags: sli

This might be a bit of an odd one. But I've been wondering if its possible to run both my monitors without dedicating a whole GPU to the second monitor.

I'm running 2x GTX 770 2GB in SLI on a 4k Samsung screen, with a Full HD screen as secondary. Though these cards are getting pretty old, and I often require both when playing demanding games. At the same time, I enjoy the luxury of a dual monitor setup.
Is it possible to simply use the 2nd GPU partly for the secondary screen? (like when running dual monitors on a single GPU)

Edit (thank you for the comment Attie): I currently have my main monitor connected with a display port cable in GPU 1, and secondary monitor in GPU 2 with HDMI. I've tried connecting my main monitor through the motherboard, and secondary in the 1st GPU, though this seems to really confuse my pc and results in it only starting up with both monitors running occasionally. Regardless of this, I've found that it does not really matter how I connect the monitors, as Nvidia Control panel doesn't seem to allow to partially use a GPU for a secondary screen. This is where I got stuck.

Comment: How are your displays connected? What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: SLI combines the resources of 2 GPUs and turns them into a single card, to the system, it would see a single card.  More is actually going on, but this is vastly different then the multiple GPU capability from Vulcan and DX12.  So your question is confusing

Comment: @Ramhound What is it that you find confusing, I might be able to explain it better. Though regarding your comment, that is what I'm trying to achieve. If my system were to view it as a singular unit my problems would be solved.

Comment: You connect your displayed to a single card, because of the limitations of how SLI and Crossfire work, but doing so shouldn't effect performance.

Comment: So you're saying I should connect both monitors to the same card? i will try that and report back.